# Carathéodory metric on product domain

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be a bounded domain. Consider the Carathéodory metric $C_G$ on $G$. If $G=\mathbb{D}^n$ (unit polydisc), then $C_G(a,z)=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}p(a_j,z_j)$, where $p$ denotes the Poincaré metric on $\mathbb{D}$.

My question: Is there a similar formula in case $D=\mathbb{B}^2\times \mathbb{D}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^3$, where $\mathbb{B}^2$ denotes the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$? More generally, is there a formula (or some estimate) for the Carathéodory metric of the product domain, in terms of the Carathéodory metric on the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general formula, you should check out Kobayashi's book *Hyperbolic Complex Spaces*. In Proposition 3.1.11 of that text, he proves the following:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be complex spaces. For $(x,y), (x',y') \in X\times Y$, we have
> $$
> \text{max}\{ c_X(x,x'),c_Y(y,y')\} \leq c_{X\times Y}((x,y),(x',y')) \leq c_X(x,x') + c_Y(y,y').
> $$

Comment: Theorem 4.9.1 of this text says that for complex spaces $X,Y$, the left inequality becomes equality. I am not familiar with "complex spaces", can you refer some text dealing with "complex spaces" so that I have some examples of complex spaces.

Comment: Is a ball (Euclidean) an example of a complex space? In general, what about a bounded domain?

Comment: @Jean: a complex space is a generalization of a complex manifold and also a generalization of a complex analytic variety. In particular, every bounded domain is a complex space.

Comment: @Jean the below answer by Peter Pflug is the one you should look at. In particular, Theorem 4.9.1 of the text refers to the reference he mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there is the product property $\max\{c_X(x,x′),c_Y(y,y′)\}=c_{X×Y}((x,y),(x′,y′))$ for arbitrary domains $X, Y$. See chapter 18 in "Invariant distances and metrics in complex analysis" de Gruyter (2013).